# Do you know how to write the code of simuLTE?

Tags: omnet++, lte, simulte

I want to implement mt new algorithms of Scheduler in simuLTE. Could anyone give me an example how how to write the code ??? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of new algorithm is dependent on the exact requirement or use case you have in hand.

The eNB shall prepare a schedule list for DL and UL direction for every TTI, which will have the available resources and related information based on the policy. This is performed by a member of the eNB Scheduler called Scheduling Policy.

At high level, for implementation of new algorithms, you may need to change the schedule() function that comprises of 2 steps such as preparation of policy based details (schedule details)and enforcement, construction of PDUs based on data from buffer and policy Also, you may need to accordingly update rtxSchedule() function as per your requirements.